# Colour specific cells from two columns that don't match, using python pandas style.where (or otherwise) and export to excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, styleframe

I am looking to colour specific cells from two columns that don't match, but would like to use it with python pandas [style.where](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.where.html#pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.where) and export in excel using openpyxl.

My code so far:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'config_dummy1': ["dummytext"] * 100,
    'config_size_x': ["textstring"] * 100,
    'config_size_y': ["textstring"] * 100,
    'config_dummy2': ["dummytext"] * 100
})
df.at[50, 'config_size_x'] = "xandydontmatch"
df.at[99, 'config_size_y'] = "xandydontmatch"
print(df)
df.style.where(
    df['config_size_x'] != df['config_size_y'],
    'color: #ffffff; background-color: #ba3018',
    other=''
).to_excel('styled.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
```

I am stuck, as it produces an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python-match-csv.py", line 205, in <module>
    main2()
  File "python-match-csv.py", line 131, in main2
    ).to_excel('styled.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
  File "F:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\style.py", line 175, in to_excel
    engine=engine)
  File "F:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\excel.py", line 652, in write
    freeze_panes=freeze_panes)
  File "F:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 1390, in write_cells
    for cell in cells:
  File "F:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\excel.py", line 617, in get_formatted_cells
    self._format_body()):
  File "F:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\excel.py", line 529, in _format_regular_rows
    for cell in self._generate_body(coloffset):
  File "F:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\excel.py", line 601, in _generate_body
    styles = self.styler._compute().ctx
  File "F:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\style.py", line 514, in _compute
    r = func(self)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\style.py", line 604, in _applymap
    result = self.data.loc[subset].applymap(func)
  File "F:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 6072, in applymap
    return self.apply(infer)
  File "F:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 6014, in apply
    return op.get_result()
  File "F:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 318, in get_result
    return super(FrameRowApply, self).get_result()
  File "F:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 142, in get_result
    return self.apply_standard()
  File "F:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 248, in apply_standard
    self.apply_series_generator()
  File "F:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 277, in apply_series_generator
    results[i] = self.f(v)
  File "F:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 6070, in infer
    return lib.map_infer(x.astype(object).values, func)
  File "pandas/_libs/src\inference.pyx", line 1472, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
  File "F:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\style.py", line 671, in <lambda>
    return self.applymap(lambda val: value if cond(val) else other,
TypeError: ("'Series' object is not callable", 'occurred at index config_dummy1')
```

TypeError: ("'Series' object is not callable", 'occurred at index config_dummy1'

I am open to suggestions other than .where(), I also tried to do this with .apply() but failed.

Note: the column index position is not fixed, it could be `config_size_x, config_dummy1, config_dummy2, config_size_y` or any other combination

Note 2: using windows and python 3.6 if it matters

Comment: `the column index position is not fixed, it could be config_size_x, config_dummy1, config_dummy2, config_size_y or any other combination` - so need compare `config_dummy1` with `config_dummy2` and similar for each pairs? DataFrame always contains columns pairs?

Comment: DataFrame contains a lot (about 50-60 columns) of config_COLNAME_y and config_COLNAME_x which are **not** in the same index position every time. config_size_x and config_size_y is one of them, but if I get this right, I can build my way from there. Yes they are always in _x and _y pairs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create DataFrame of styles with `apply`:

```
def color(x):
    c1 = 'color: #ffffff; background-color: #ba3018'
    m = x['config_size_x'] != x['config_size_y']
    df1 = pd.DataFrame('', index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
    df1.loc[m, ['config_size_x', 'config_size_y']] = c1
    return df1

df.style.apply(color, axis=None)
```

General solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'config_dummy1': ["dummytext"] * 10,
    'a_y': ["a"] * 10,
    'config_size_x': ["textstring"] * 10,
    'config_size_y': ["textstring"] * 10,
    'config_dummy2': ["dummytext"] * 10,
    'a_x': ["a"] * 10
})
df.at[5, 'config_size_x'] = "xandydontmatch"
df.at[9, 'config_size_y'] = "xandydontmatch"
df.at[0, 'a_x'] = "xandydontmatch"
df.at[3, 'a_y'] = "xandydontmatch"
print(df)

def color(x):
    c1 = 'color: #ffffff; background-color: #ba3018'
    df1 = pd.DataFrame('', index=x.index, columns=x.columns)

    #select only columns ends with _x and _y and sorting
    cols = sorted(x.filter(regex='_x$|_y$').columns)
    #loop by pairs and assign style by mask
    for i, j in zip(cols[::2],cols[1::2]):
        #pairs columns 
        #print (i, j)
        m = x[i] != x[j]
        df1.loc[m, [i, j]] = c1
    return df1

df.style.apply(color, axis=None).to_excel('styled.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply and I see the apply() approach, but unfortunately it colours the whole row. Is there a way to colour the specific cells of config_size_x and config_size_y only?

Comment: Yes, they are sorted in the end. I admire your zeal! :)

Comment: @SavvasRadevic - Just added solution for non sorting input data, please check it. :)

Comment: thank you! I had a small issue with NaN values, for some reason they were being colored (I was probably checking empty '' strings with NaN). `df.fillna('')` did it, all is well! Speed is something that needs improving, it takes ~40 seconds for 437 rows and 90 columns (compared to the couple of seconds required before applying the styles). But as far as I've understood that's an issue with the `apply()` in dataframes. I will play with it and see if I can improve it. :D

Comment: I fixed the index too with `df.index = pd.RangeIndex(len(df.index))` and now it takes 20 seconds which is bearable at least for me.

Answer (score 3):

Since this question is tagged with `styleframe`:

```
from StyleFrame import StyleFrame, Styler

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2], 'b': [1, 3]})

sf = StyleFrame(df)
sf.apply_style_by_indexes(sf[sf['a'] != sf['b']], styler_obj=Styler(bg_color='red'))
sf.to_excel('test.xlsx').save()
```

Will produce

[image]

If you want to color only a subset of the mismatching rows you can simply use `cols_to_style` param:

```
sf.apply_style_by_indexes(sf[sf['a'] != sf['b']], styler_obj=Styler(bg_color='red'),
                          cols_to_style=['a', 'b'])
```

[image]

Comment: I'm open to any workaround suggestion :) I forgot to mention that I've also tried styleframe and failed to colour specific cells. :D Unfortunately, your answer colours the whole row. Is there a way to colour the specific cells of config_size_x and config_size_y only?

Comment: @SavvasRadevic Yes, quite easily. See my updated answer

Comment: This answer is also valid! Thank you very much! I've had an issue with my index, it was complaining `IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds` on cols_to_style. I solved it using `df.index = pd.RangeIndex(len(df.index))` before the styleframe. Also it takes about the same time as the other answer (with a foreach loop on the column pairs).